# Creating a check constraint using liquibase

Tags: database, constraints, liquibase, check-constraints

What are the options for adding check constraints to columns in tables when using Liquibase?

I have tried using the Liquibase checkConstraint attribute, but it doesn't seem to work, possibly because it is a Liquibase Pro change type.

```
<column name="age" type="INT" >
    <constraints checkConstraint="CHECK (age &gt;= 0 AND age &lt;= 1000)"/>
</column>
```

Another option I found is using the  tag to execute an ALTER TABLE statement, but I'm concerned about potential compatibility issues with different databases.

```
<sql>
    ALTER TABLE person_jn ADD CONSTRAINT check_age CHECK (age &gt;=0 AND age &lt;= 1000)
</sql>
```

Are there any other recommended approaches or best practices for adding check constraints to columns in Liquibase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, check constraint change is for LiquibasePro only.

You can use `<sql>` change and add it in plain SQL.

If you're worried about compatibility issues, you can always use `dbms` attribute of the changeSet, which allows you to create different changeSets for different databases.

E.g.:

```
<changeSet id="foo-1" author="bar" dbms="mysql">
    <!-- preConditions -->
    <sql>
        <!-- SQL for MySQL -->
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="foo-2" author="bar" dbms="postgresql">
    <!-- preConditions -->
    <sql>
        <!-- SQL for Postgres -->
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

From the changeSet [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changeset.html)

> dbms (optional) - Specifies which database type(s) a changeset is to be used for. See valid database type names on Liquibase Database Tutorials. Separate multiple databases with commas. Specify that a changeset is not applicable to a particular database type by prefixing with !. The keywords all and none are also available.

Here's are lists of supported databases:

https://docs.liquibase.com/start/tutorials/home.html

https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/directory/database-tutorials/